# Laravel controller not outputting content as real JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have the following controller on my `Laravel` application:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function index() {
        $projects = Project::where('is_completed', false)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_completed', false);
            }])->get();
        return $projects->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    ...
}
```

which is referenced by the following route:

```
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
```

My **problem is** that when I go to the url:

```
https://127.0.0.1/api/projects
```

Then I get the expected result but the content type is not `JSON` as you can see below (it is `HTML`):

[image]

Any idea on how can I output the content as real `JSON` content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$projects = Project::where('is_completed', false)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_completed', false);
    }])->get();
return $projects->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

you should use:

```
return response()->json(Project::where('is_completed', false)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_completed', false);
    }])->get());
```

Take a look at example of [Json response in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses)